# Two way communication program using UDP not working properly

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I am trying to write a two way chat program using UDP in C++. Here is my code:

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string>
    enum { RECV_PORT = 5023, MSGSIZE = 1024 };
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(sockaddr) ;
    int receiver( int socket_fd )
    {
        sockaddr_in my_addr ;
        std::memset( &my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr) ) ;
        my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
        my_addr.sin_port = htons( RECV_PORT ) ;
        my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY ;
        if ( bind( socket_fd, (sockaddr*)&my_addr, addr_len ) != 0 )
           return 2 ;
         sockaddr_in client_addr ;
        while( true )
        {
            char recv_data[MSGSIZE+1] ;

            int bytes_recd = recvfrom( socket_fd, recv_data, MSGSIZE, 0,
                                    (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addr_len ) ;
            if( bytes_recd == -1 ) break ;
            recv_data[bytes_recd] = '\0' ;
            std::cout << "Message from " << inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr)
                      << ':' << ntohs(client_addr.sin_port) << " - "
                      << recv_data << std::endl ;


        std::string send_str ;
        while( std::getline( std::cin, send_str ) )
        {
          send_str.resize(MSGSIZE) ;
          sendto( socket_fd, send_str.c_str(), MSGSIZE, 0,
                (sockaddr*)&client_addr, addr_len ) ;
        }

        return 0 ;
    }
}
    int sender( int socket_fd )
    {
        std::cout << "IP Address of server: " ;
        std::string address ; 
        std::cin >> address >> std::ws ;
        sockaddr_in member_addr ;
        std::memset( &member_addr, 0, sizeof(member_addr) ) ;
        member_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
        member_addr.sin_port = htons( RECV_PORT ) ;
        member_addr.sin_addr.s_addr =
                 *(in_addr_t*)(gethostbyname( address.c_str() )->h_addr) ;
        std::string send_str ;
        while( std::getline( std::cin, send_str ) )
        {
          send_str.resize(MSGSIZE) ;


 sendto( socket_fd, send_str.c_str(), MSGSIZE, 0,
            (sockaddr*)&member_addr, addr_len ) ;
    }
    while( true )
    {
        sockaddr_in server_addr ;
        char recv_data[MSGSIZE+1] ;

        int bytes_recd = recvfrom( socket_fd, recv_data, MSGSIZE, 0,
                                (sockaddr*)&server_addr, &addr_len ) ;
        if( bytes_recd == -1 ) break ;
            recv_data[bytes_recd] = '\0' ;
            std::cout << "Message from " << inet_ntoa(server_addr.sin_addr)
                      << ':' << ntohs(server_addr.sin_port) << " - "
                      << recv_data << std::endl ;
        }
        return 0 ;
    }
    int main()
    {
      int socket_fd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 ) ;
      if( socket_fd == -1 ) return 1 ;
      return fork() == 0 ? receiver( socket_fd ) : sender( socket_fd ) ;
    }
```

When I type a message on the client window, the message is displayed on the server window, but when I type a message on the server window, then the message is displayed not he server window only and not on the client window. Why is this happening? Can somebody please help me fix this?

Comment: If the problem is UDP and not your code: Are you aware that UDP just isn´t reliable? Messages may be lost. (Even if your code is perfect.)

Comment: I know that but I feel that my sendto function from my server(the receiver function) is not working properly. That's why it's sending and the server is only receiving the message and displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Do not code this with `fork(2)` - your parent and child processes *`share`* the same socket (child inherits parent's file descriptors). That surely messes everything up.

Just introduce a command line parameter telling `main()` which mode to operate in - sender or receiver - and run them in different terminal windows (eventually on different computers).

Comment: Or `fork` before calling `socket`. But having the two processes share a socket is definitely a bad thing -- there's a race for which process binds the socket.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by telling main() which mode to operate it. Could you explain?

Comment: Something like this: `~$ ./my_prog -s 7777` means starting your program as a server listening on port 7777, but `~$ ./my_prog -c 10.0.0.3 7777` means starting it as a client that talks to the server at IP address `10.0.0.3` and port `7777`.

Answer (score 0):

> > When I type a message on the client window..

You have separate terminal sessions? You are forking and binding to a port in one of the process(same SD as well). Hence running another instance of program from separate windows, wouldn't it have bind error? Though, your `receiver` logic would run. You should based on command line arguments decide whether the program instance is to be a client or a server.

BTW,the issue is, you are in a while loop in sender and receiver. In sender in `while(true)` loop for getting input from user and sending. And in other receving the data on socket. Obviously, one is destined to only receive data and the other to send data. It isn't bi-directional.

Comment: How to make it bi-directional then?

Comment: I hope you got the point. In receiver function you are in constant loop doing `recvfrom`. Your attempt for `getline` is out of the loop.  Move the `getline` code inside loop. The loop should do `recvfrom`, then `getline` and then `sendto`

Comment: Ya I understand, but it still doesn't seem to work. I updated my code above in the question according to what you're saying.

Comment: Look at sender. There is 'recvfrom' in while loop. Sender won't get send after the first time